# Calling second Intent in onActivityResult of nested Fragment won't call onActivityResult again

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult, android-savedstate

I call the Camera intent in a nested fragment and get the image in onActivityResult in the fragment without any problems. As I want to crop the image I call a (second) intent in the onActivityResult to pass the image to the Crop intent. However, the onActivityResult is not called in this case (*Only relevant if the application is terminated in the background during one of the intents*).

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {

        // Camera onActivityResult
        case INTENT_CAMERA:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IN CARD ONACTIVITY - CAMERA INTENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                String uriString = getPrefs.getString("photoUri", null);
                if (uriString != null) {

                    Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(uriString);

                    Intent intent = CropImage.activity(selectedImage).setAspectRatio(1, 1).setMinCropResultSize(800, 800).getIntent(getContext());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_CROP);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            break;

        // Crop ActivityOnResult
        case INTENT_CROP:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IN CARD ONACTIVITY - CROP INTENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(imageReturnedIntent);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), resultUri);
                    uploadImage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
    }
}
```

I found the following line in the logs:

```
W/FragmentActivity: Activity result no fragment exists for who: android:fragment:0:1
```

This is only thrown when the crop intent is called - not for the first camera intent. Do I have to wait for the fragment to be created again before calling the second intent? Or is there any other reliable way to handle this situation? Thank you!

Activity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Nav Drawer Variables
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

private PrefManager prefManager;

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = null;
FragmentTransaction transaction;
String FRAGMENT_TAG;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prefManager = new PrefManager(this);


    // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Set navigation view
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    View v = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    // Find drawer view
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

    // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
    mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    // Find drawer view
    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    // Setup drawer view
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);


    //Set Progress Bar Invisible
    FrameLayout progressFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressFrame);
    progressFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    // Switch between hamburger and back button
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // show back button
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                //show hamburger
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                drawerToggle.syncState();
                toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    // Handle Fragments
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        fragment = fragmentManager.getFragment(savedInstanceState, "fragment");
        transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
    } else {
        // Insert the inital fragment
        Class fragmentClass = Fragment1.class;
        FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_1";
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

            transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked

    Class fragmentClass = null;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_1";
            fragmentClass = Fragment1.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_mychallenges:
            FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_2";
            fragmentClass = Fragment2.class;
            break;
        case R.id.nav_feedback:
            FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_3";
            fragmentClass = Fragment3.class;
            break;
        default:
FRAGMENT_TAG = "FRAGMENT_1";
            fragmentClass = Fragment1.class;
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment

    transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();

    // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    // Set action bar title
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    // Close the navigation drawer
    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


// `onPostCreate` called when activity start-up is complete after `onStart()`
// NOTE! Make sure to override the method with only a single `Bundle` argument
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();

}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    fragmentManager.putFragment(outState, "fragment", fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flContent));
    Log.d("TAG", "CURRENT_FRAGMENT: " + fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flContent));
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

}
```

**EDIT:**

ParentFragment:

```
public class FragmentProcess extends Fragment {


Fragment childFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_process, container, false);
    TextView processTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    processTitle.setText("Title");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    loadData();
}

private void loadData() {


        String url = "example.com ";
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        // RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                subChallengesString = response;

                insertNestedFragment();


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


}

// Embeds the child fragment dynamically
private void insertNestedFragment() {



    childFragment = new FragmentProcessChallengeCard();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.process_challenge_child_fragment, childFragment).commit();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    //Save the fragment's state here
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your activity code?

Comment: @JayminPanchal I added the activity code above

Comment: are you sure you are calling the cropImage Intent properly?

Comment: @NewbieAndroid Yes, the intent is started and I am able to crop the image, but once I return the onResult method is not called. I am using this [library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you are using has written that onActivityResult method of the parent Activity will get called. Check your onActivityResult of Parent Activity and create a method or interface to send the same result to your fragment.

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
   CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
   } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
       Exception error = result.getError();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Activity result from your activity to fragment.

Just try this code in your `activity` and check if it work or not.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.flContent);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: This way the onActivityResult() in the child fragment isn't called at all. Not even for the first time for the camera intent.. I'll add some code from the parent fragment in my answer. Maybe that will help to understand the issue.